# Fulltext index or composite index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, query-optimization

I have two tables like this :

**Enterprises**

```
FullName      Type
ABC aze        1
DEF rty        2
```

**Addresses**

```
Address1          Address2 Address3    Postcode    City
165 Ward Street                        E1 7AW      London
167 Ward Street                        E1 7AW      London
10 Auckland Street                     N1 0AA      London
```

I will make a lot of queries to search if the address exists and/or the enterprise exists with `=`.

For the enterprise's query, it will be on `VARCHAR` and `SMALLINT` (Type column) fields : `WHERE Type = 1 AND FullName = '...'`

For the addresse's query, it will be on `VARCHAR` fields : `WHERE address1 = '...' AND address2 = '...' AND address3 = '...' AND postcode = '...' AND city = '...'`

To have best response time, should I use composite index or `FULLTEXT` index ?

Answer (score 0):

[`Full-text`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) searching is performed using `MATCH()` `AGAINST()` syntax, since you are using `WHERE` and operator `=` means you are searching the exact string, so the composite index is the best choice for you :

```
create index entreprises_idx on Enterprises(FullName, Type);

create index addresses_idx on Addresses(address1, address1, address1, postcode, city);
```

If you want to run a full text search then you must have a full text index on the columns you'll be running it against.

Comment: Just a heads-up.  FULLTEXT searching can give odd results when used on small datasets. And, it often needs some kind of user intervention to inspect the result set and choose one result. Thus, it's really effective when used for an autocomplete feature in a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  Composite index.

Long answer:

```
WHERE Type = 1 AND FullName = '...'
```

-->

```
INDEX(Type, FullName)   -- (either order is ok)


WHERE address1 = '...' AND address2 = '...' AND
      address3 = '...' AND postcode = '...' AND city = '...'
```

-->

```
INDEX(address1, address2, address3, postcode, city)  -- (any order)
```

The above indexes will be faster than FULLTEXT because it is a perfect match (all `=`, no ranges, etc).

Don't you need to worry about "fuzzy" matching?  If you do, neither `INDEX`, nor `FULLTEXT` will be of much use.